# Looping over Array Elements By Calling them by Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

How do I loop over an Array which has 5 elements. I have 5 elements with ids like imgone, imgtwo, imgthree, imgfour, imgfive.

```
var ids =
[ 
    "#imgone",
    "#imgtwo",
    "#imgthree",
    "#imgfour",
    "#imgfive"
]; 
for (var i = 0; id = ids[i]; i++)
{  
    $(id).click(function() {

        $("#cell1,#cell2,#cell3,#cell4,#cell5").hide(); 
         $("#cell" + (i+1)).show(); 

    });
}
});
```

Then I have an 5 a tag elements like

```
<a href="#"  id="imgone"><img src ="myimage1" /></a>    
<a href="#"  id="imgtwo"><img src ="myimage2" /></a>    
<a href="#"  id="imgthree"><img src ="myimage3" /></a>    
<a href="#"  id="imgfour"><img src ="myimage4" /></a>    
<a href="#"  id="imgfive"><img src ="myimage5" /></a>
```

cell1 , cell2, et-al are my blocks that I need to show/hide onclick of a elements.

btw this code always hides all the cell blocks and shows cell6, which does not exist in my code.
I mean    `$("#cell" + (i+1)).show();`     never takes values of i as 0, 1 , 2 , 3 or 4.

So how do I iterate over an array and show hide my cells. I think something is wrong with this line of code `$(id).click(function()` but can't figure out what???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a closure issue, the variable `i` points to the `i` used in the loop, and at the time of execution it is always `6`.

use this code instead

```
for (var i = 0; id = ids[i]; i++)
{  
    var fnc = function(j){
        return function() {
            $("#cell1,#cell2,#cell3,#cell4,#cell5").hide(); 
            $("#cell" + (j+1)).show();
        };
    }(i);
    $(id).click(fnc);
}
```

For more on javascript closures see [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 1):

you could jquerify it :

```
var ids =
[ 
    "#imgone",
    "#imgtwo",
    "#imgthree",
    "#imgfour",
    "#imgfive"
]; 
$(ids.join(,)).each(function(i){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $("#cell1,#cell2,#cell3,#cell4,#cell5").hide(); 
        $("#cell" + (i+1)).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: $(this).click(function(){
Control never gets inside this function. and btw what is this function parameter i

Comment: i is the index of the iterated element. see more at http://api.jquery.com/each/. Why do you say this doesn't work?

Comment: coz it didn't, though it should. Why I am saying control never gets inside this function, coz when I put a simple alert("hi") after $(this).click(function {....
it didnt got executed. have u tried it??

Comment: what version of jquery do you use?

Comment: i don't know in witch version of jquery the array-of-selectors selector was introduced ($([selector1,selector2,...selectorn]) ), so you could try using the selectors separated by comma : $(selector1,selector2,..selectorn).see update